# Flask pagination redirect

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a web store that uses `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy` in which I implemented pagination on the home page with a route like this:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    data = Product.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=6)
    return render_template('home.html', data=data)
```

The issue I'm having is with the search function which is like this:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    query = request.args['search']
    if len(query) > 0:
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        data = Product.query.filter(Product.name.ilike(f"%{query}%")).paginate(page=page, per_page=6)
        if data is not None:
            return render_template('home.html', data=data)
        elif data is None:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    if len(query) == 0:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

This is my `search` form:

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <form class="form-inline" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 ml-2" name="search" type="search" placeholder="Търсене" aria-label="Search">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 </form>
</li>
```

And here is the `jinja2` code for tyhe page numbers in my `home.html`:

```
{% for page_num in data.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
  {% if page_num %}
     {% if data.page == page_num %}
       <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('home', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
     {% else %}
       <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{{ url_for('home', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
     {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I search the products the query shows the items that are being searched, but if there are multiple pages of results, when I click on the page number it redirects to the `home.html` with all the data from the first route.

Is there a way for the results to remain consistent after the search and the pages to be for the `search` function?

Comment: I think when you search and click on the page number, it takes you to the page but gives you all the records and not the filtered by search , am i right? and you want the filtered results when you click on page number?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: as I see `url_for('home', page=page_num)` what this is doing because I don't see any named parameter in route of `\home`. if you don't mind can you give me the code like github or discord because I had the same problem. also what is your html code for search

Comment: @charchit Yes, that is the idea that I got too. Right now I can't contact you for the code. What do you mean by "I don't see any named parameter in route of  \home"?

Comment: see why are you passing `page=page_num` , if you are passing then you route should be something like `@app.route("/home<page>") def home(page): [....]`

Comment: why don't you try passing the search parameter , `url_for('home', page=page_num, search=searched_string )` to the  `anchor` tag.

Comment: @charchit I've updated the question with the search form. Where do I get the `searched_string` in your last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234150/discussion-between-charchit-and-t0ny1234).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to update the query in the url

This function will take two params search in the current url for the key if exist then update it else add it.

js

```
function url_manager(key,value){
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.set(key,value );
window.location.replace(url)
}
```

replace the anchor tags with button tag `<button class="page_num_btn_class btn btn-info mb-4" type="button">{{ page_num }}</button>`

Note- you must have jquery included

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" ></script>
```

you can call click event on the button

```
$(".page_num_btn_class").click(function (e){
url_manager("page",$(this).text())
})
```